# build an endorsement map for political candidate

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am in the process of building out a website for a political candidate her in the UK, one thing that I would like to include is an endorsement map such as the one used [here](http://www.toomeyforsenate.com). Ive looked for information on how they are created but have drawn a blank so I was hoping the community could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) and create a function to create a marker when the supporter gives you there location. Hope its of some use :)